# Record video on Website an stream video to AWS Kinesis with AWS-SDK-JS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, aws-sdk-js, video-recording

With my (static) web application, a user can record his webcam. The app uploads the video to a S3 bucket via a presigned URL after recording.
However, I don't like this solution for several reasons. First, the upload takes a bit longer for very large videos and second, it is very error prone.

So instead I want to stream the video directly to AWS Kinesis. I found the SDK (WebRTC SDK in JavaScript for Web Applications) and the demo page for WebRTC with Kinesis, but in my understanding the use case for WebRTC is peer to peer video streaming (e.g. video chat). What I want is just "streaming" video to Kinesis (to be stored in a S3 bucket in the next step). The AWS documentation lists Java, Android, C and C++ 'producer libaries', which can be used to implement streaming to Kinesis, but there seems to be no JavaScript 'producer library'.

So my question is: is 'streaming' (not WebRTC) possible with JavaScript